# List of Linear and Non-Linear Data Structures

Tags: data-structures

I know the concept of linearity in data structures. But I want to know that what **Data Structures** are **Linear** and what are **Non-Linear**. Please show me the list of both types of data structures that we use commonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation that also gives some [examples](http://www.careerride.com/Data-structure-linear-and-non-linear.aspx) for both cases.

Linear: list, array

Non-Linear: tree, graph

Answer (score 0):

In Linear Data Structures, data members are accessed sequentially.
Examples: Arrays, Linked Lists, Queues, Stacks, Double Linked Lists.

In Non-Linear Data Structures, a data member may have connections with several other data members; these structures follow no set sequence.
Examples: Graphs, Trees.